# ¿Qué significa path?

Tags: python, python-3.x

¿En el siguiente código que tipo de archivo abre `path`?

```
class Applicants:
    def _init_(self,path):
        self.list_applicants = []
        self.path = path
        try:
            obj= open(path,"rb")
            self.list_applicants = pickle.load(obj)
            obj.close()
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu código de ejemplo, `path` es la ubicación donde se encuentra el archivo generado por el modulo `pickle`, este archivo tiene guardada la lista de solicitantes (applicants). Este archivo debio ser generado con `pickle.dump()`

Por ejemplo, digamos que tienes esta lista de solicitantes:

```
appl = ["javier", "nick", "maria"]
```

Lo que te permite pickle es que este objeto (una lista en este caso) lo guardes en un archivo para utilizarlo despues.

Con este código lo guardas en el disco en un archivo llamado *appl*:

```
with open('appl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(appl, f)
```

Luego si quieres abrir ese archivo más tarde, ejecutas esto:

```
# Abre el archivo donde guardaste la lista de solicitantes
# Tener en cuenta la ubicación exacta del archivo
with open('appl', 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

Mayor información en:

- [Docs Oficiales](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)
- [What is pickle](http://pythontips.com/2013/08/02/what-is-pickle-in-python/)
- [Pickle intro](http://python.about.com/od/pythonstandardlibrary/a/pickle_intro.htm)
- [Serializing python objects](http://www.diveintopython3.net/serializing.html)

Comment: Y este archivo puede ser un archivo en bloc de notas "file.txt"?

Comment: Deja edito mi respuesta para aclarar mejor la idea

Comment: No puede ser un archivo de texto, debe ser el archivo generado por `pickle` con `pickle.dump()`.